# Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I am working on google charts with angularjs. My functionality is working fine, but issue is when i click on the legend it is throwing the error which can be seen in the browser console and i know the error is causing because of the below code :

```
$scope.serverId = chart1.data.rows[selectedItem.row].c[3].v;
alert("serverid : " + $scope.serverId);
```

The above code is required to get the assigned server ID when user click on any of the line in the chart and it is returning the ID, issue is when user click on the legend, it has to disable the corresponding line in the chart and when this scenario is tested i can see the error in the browser console. Any inputs how to resolve that error ??

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
    at $$childScopeClass.$scope.seriesSelected
```

I still want the code to get the serverID. [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/j0eP0UsjTzudUQ5IJGIN?p=preview) for demo. Please click on the tip of the lines in the demo plunker to notice the alert and when clicked on the legend you can notice the error in the browser console.

Comment: The plunker works for me.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Not if you click on the legend on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no value for `selectedItem.row`, then the property 'c' would by default be undefined. Wrap that with a check to see if the parent object exists first.

```
  if (chart1.data.rows[selectedItem.row]) {
       $scope.serverId = chart1.data.rows[selectedItem.row].c[3].v;
      alert("serverid : " + $scope.serverId);
  }
```

Comment: Now i can hide the data by selecting the legends and i can select the legends which hide the data and no data on the chart is visible if i  select all the legends.I want atleast one line should be visible on the graph.Is there a way to handle such that if user selects 3 legends to disable out of 4 legends and again he is selecting the 4th legend it should not allow user to select it, instead throw an alert/message saying cannot hide all the information.